# Probability of finding a set of balls with the same color

Tags: probability

A bag has $n$ balls of $k$ colors. Each color has $r$ balls. That is, $n = kr$. I understand that the probability of picking $r$ balls and the balls being of the same color is ${n \choose r}^{-1}$. But if we evenly divide the $n$ balls into $s$ groups (we can assume that $s$ always divides $n$) where the balls of the same color always go into the same group and then randomly pick $r$ balls out of the $n$ balls, what is the probability that all the $r$ balls are of the same color and are in the same group? The picked $r$ balls can come from one or more groups. For instance, if we divide the $n$ balls into 2 groups, $g_1$, and $g_2$ and pick 2 balls, the two balls can come from only $g_1$, only $g_2$, or both $g_1$ and $g_2$.

I have two conflicting thoughts:

1. It's the same as randomly picking $r$ balls out of the bag, namely ${n \choose r}^{-1}$.
2. It should be the $s^{-1}{\frac{n}{s} \choose r}^{-1}$. That is, the probability is the probability of randomly selecting a group times the probability of the $r$ balls picked from this group have the same color.

My simulation shows that the first thought is correct, but I'm not sure why the second thought is incorrect. Could you anyone please help me understand what I missed?

Thanks,

In case it matters, I was trying to simply the setup of my problem. The real problem I'm working on is a cluster has $n$ machines. The cluster hosts some data, which is partitioned $k$ ways. Each partition has a $r$ replicas. No machine will host more than one replica of the same partition. If $r$ machine fail and each of the machine contains a replica of a same partition, then the partition will be lost. I'm trying to figure out if breaking this cluster into $s$ smaller clusters will reduce the probability of partition loss.

Comment: Re "In understand that:" not quite.  The correct chance of a monochromatic sample of size $r$ is $r/\binom{n}{r}.$ For instance, consider the case of $n\ge 2$ and $r=1,$ so $n=k.$ In a sample of size $1$ it is certain all balls will be will be the same color, but your formula says the chance is only $1/\binom{n}{r}=1/n\lt 1.$  As to your main question, the statement is ambiguous: please explain more precisely what you mean by "randomly pick $r$ balls from any number of the groups."

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I clarified the question. I meant one can randomly pick r balls from the n balls, while the picked balls can be in one group or multiple.

Comment: I still cannot follow what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you could supply a simple example of this process?